# Align noisy point clouds

Tags: gaussian-mixture-distribution, high-dimensional

I have a point cloud $X$ that, I suspect, is a translate of a Gaussian-corrupted version of a subset of a larger cloud $Y$, both high-dimensional ($d$ is at least 100 and ideally 10,000). What is the best way of recovering the translate here? I tried a naive EM algorithm based on a Gaussian mixture model but it's almost a non-starter, since the correspondence probabilities are so low.

Edit: I am analyzing RNA-seq data and have two datasets of cell archetypes - these are just vectors in high-dimensional space. These sets were constructed on different machines, and I think that the technical difference between the two datasets is a component-wise (positive) multiplier, or after a log transform, a translate. I'd like to recover the translate to see which archetypes are present across datasets. I tried the EM algorithm for this (a modified version of what appears in Myronenko and Song's "Non-rigid point set registration: Coherent Point Drift") but because the dimensionaliy is so high every point has almost zero probability of belonging to every class in the other dataset, even when guessing initial translates. Is there a different way to go about solving this problem?

Comment: Perhaps you should show in detail your problem formulation and solution with the naive EM algorithm based on a Gaussian mixture model, and describe in detail your view of what is deficient with your formulation and/or solution..

Comment: Two questions:
1. How many elements do the clouds $X$ and $Y$ have? I am asking because simple heuristics may involve testing (all) subsets of $Y$ with size $|X|$.
2. Are you sure $X$ is a translate and would like to recover it or are you looking for some kind of hypothesis test to decide whether $X$ really is a translate?

Comment: A hypothesis test would be great but I'm focused on the correspondence. The numbers of elements in each set are actually quite small - approximately $|X| = 80$ and  $|Y| = 30$ - but one problem is that I expect that there are two effects creating $Y$ from $X$. It should be in some sense a subset, but it should also be "higher-resolution" than $X$, so it contains points that $X$ does not. So really I'd need to rest all subsets against all other subsets, and from a statistical perspective that's massive multiple comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I'm not sure if this will work in your case, but I made a minimal working example that at least works for my generated data.

## Outline

- Normalize all your 1000 variables separately for each point cloud, (*it is shown in the code below*)
- Calculate the *k* nearest neighbours between the two normalized sets.
- Find the 10 closest points based on a threshold.
- Estimate the transformation for these 10 points.
- Apply the transformation on the smaller data set, so it should be aligned with the bigger one.
- Do PCA on the larger dataset and plot the first two PCs
- Project the smaller data set onto the first two PCs you got in the last step.
- Visually inspect where you have close matches and if there is an obvious structure.

## Here is some code to achieve much of this!

```
library('RANN')
library(MASS)
# Generate X data
X <- mvrnorm(n=80,mu=rep(1,1000),Sigma = diag(1000))    
# Pick 20 from Xdata to use and add noise
Y <- X[1:20,] + 0.1*mvrnorm(n=20,mu=rep(0,1000),diag(1000))
# Add 10 new discoveries in Y
Y <- rbind(Y,mvrnorm(n=10,mu=rep(1,1000),diag(1000)))
# Add a translation to Y and take log
Y <- log(Y+10)
DATA <- data.frame(X)
QUERY <- data.frame(Y)

# Normalize the data sets
# this normalize function is from the sparseLDA package
library(sparseLDA)
normDat <- normalize(X)
normDat <- normDat$Xc

normQuer <- normalize(Y)
normQuer <- normQuer$Xc
nearest <- nn2(normDat,normQuer)
```

## What I get:

If I now look at the `nearest$nn.idx` object, the first column represents the best match and it looks as follows:

```
> nearest$nn.idx
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    1   65   42   70   21   59   52   29   57    54
[2,]    2   73   39   67   45   58   48   54   80    74
[3,]    3   44   74   67   54   38   78   22   48     1
[4,]    4   73   25   33   50    5   75   45   54    55
[5,]    5   52   64   55   57   47   61   24   58    50
[6,]    6   62   57   73   50   71   59   69   37    79
[7,]    7   29   38   35   50   67   28   45   25    47
[8,]    8   66   74   25   37   64   67   39   31    63
[9,]    9   52   58   39   57   67   40   51   62    19
[10,]   10   62   38   74   41   65   42   70   61    25
[11,]   11   43   54   37   32   19   51   38   30    73
[12,]   12   67   19   65   59   24   58   68   31    38
[13,]   13   41   43   24   57   25   30   51   22    76
[14,]   14   30   58   33   24   38   52   27   26    64
[15,]   15   76   24   75   44   67   65   68   50    38
[16,]   16   67   72   73   53   74   39   31   23    79
[17,]   17   39   54   76   79   52   21   41   33    67
[18,]   18   40   31   67   54   52   39   57   75    47
[19,]   19   71   65   29   58   54   42   23   36    70
[20,]   20   67   56   58   48   66   18   30   23    31
[21,]   50   57   60   25   29   75    1   31   58    38
[22,]   75   25   50   48   53   39   69   67   38    68
[23,]   24   38   77   71   58   57   67   50   60    55
[24,]   67   74   38   50   24   37   65   44   30    23
[25,]   66   60   28   50   65   36   62    4   40    26
[26,]   31   57   30   40   22   38   27   37   67    64
[27,]   57   37   36    1   58   29   26   50   21    67
[28,]   66   67   74   24   36   55   31   58   60    69
[29,]   57   37   36   52   48   51   29   80   40    62
[30,]   44   66   70   55   57   40   35   31   59    30
```

You can see that I have correctly found the match for the first twenty points, like I constructed this dummy data. Now you have to follow the steps as I described above to proceed.

This is probably not robust to rotations of the dataset... But if your dataset is very high dimensional, and you do not have too collinear variables, I think this will work well.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are only looking for a translate and the number of points is not too large a more pedestrian approach might be feasible. There is no guarantee that the following ideas will work but it seems plausible to me and is easy to implement. It relies on first identifying matching pairs of points and then taking those to estimate the translate.

### 1. Identify matching pairs

Denote by $Y=\{y_1,\ldots,y_N\}$ the larger set and with $X=\{x_1,\ldots,x_M\}$ the smaller set containing the translated points with noise. There is an unknown inclusion $\tau:\{1,\ldots,M\}\rightarrow\{1,\ldots,N\}$ mapping the points from $X$ to their matching counterparts in the larger set $Y$. For matching points with $k=\tau(i)$ you have the equation:
$$ x_i = y_k + a + \epsilon_i$$ where $a$ is the unknown translate and $\epsilon_i\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\Sigma)$ the Gaussian error. For matching pairs of points $(k,l) = (\tau(i),\tau(j))$ you find:
$$ x_{ij}=x_i - x_j = y_k-y_l + \epsilon_i - \epsilon_j.$$ 
Writing $y_{kl}=y_k-y_l$ and $\epsilon_{ij}=\epsilon_i-\epsilon_j$ the length of the difference between the connecting vectors is:
$$ \lVert x_{ij} - y_{kl}\rVert^2 = \lVert \epsilon_{ij}\rVert^2.$$

Since the distribution of $\epsilon_{ij}$ is normal, the distribution of $\lVert \epsilon_{ij}\rVert^2$ is $\chi^2$ and you can find lower and upper bounds $l_\alpha, u_\alpha$ around the expectation such that:
$$ P(l_\alpha < \lVert \epsilon_{ij}\rVert^2 < u_\alpha)=\alpha.$$
Now call any two pairs $(i,j)$, $(k,l)$ a (potential) match if $l_\alpha < \lVert x_{ij} - y_{kl}\rVert^2< u_\alpha$.

Of course there is no guarantee that this criterion will give you all actual matches and only those. But the idea is that for true matches the noise shouldn't change the distance too much while non-matches should produce large differences because $y_k-y_l$ is pointing in a direction very different from $x_i-x_j$. Even if you have the occasional false match not all hope is lost, you can correct for this in the second step.

### 2. Estimating the translate

Every match produces two estimates for $a$:
$$ \tilde{a}_i=x_i-y_k\text{ and } \tilde{a}_j=x_j-y_l.$$
For correct matches you know that $\tilde{a}=a+\epsilon$. Hence you can recognise and eliminate outliers stemming from false matches. Finally your estimate for $a$ is just the mean of the outlier-corrected $\tilde{a}.$

For $M=30$, $N=80$ you will have $\frac{30*29}{2}=435$ connecting lines $x_{ij}$ in $X$ and $80*79=6320$ (order matters!) $y_{kl}$ in $Y$. So the calculations should be easily doable.